# What do we call a person who cannot read people?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, idioms

A person who has a low emotional IQ and is bad at reading people and decoding their expressions and body language. I don't think I need to give any statement for it.

**Edit**: They do not have any physical or mental disorders but more like lacking empathy but are not psychopaths. Looking for synonyms of 'socially illiterate'.

Comment: Are you looking for *naive?* Or perhaps *gullible?*

Comment: I am not sure about naive but they are not gullible but I am looking for the opposite of a person who lacks empathy but is not a psychopath.

Comment: Clinically speaking, this is known as *[social-emotional agnosia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social-Emotional_Agnosia)*. A less clinical term is simply socially *oblivious*.

Comment: Socially illiterate?

Comment: "**indifferent to others**" or *close, but not exactly what you are looking for*: A **social misfit** is generally thought of as someone who has different views on culture and doesn't fit in with most others in society. In recent years, the term social misfit has expanded to be used as a slur against people who don't have a lot of friends, or who find it difficult to get acclimated to a particular group.

Comment: I usually try to give such **clueless** people the benefit of the doubt and attribute their behavior to their **cluelessness** [about such matters].

Comment: I'd like to see more context to this question. What is the nature of this person? Is this person shy/anxious in social situations, or are they comfortable but simply incapable of reading others (thus lacking empathy)? You'll notice that phrases like "socially inept" can hardly apply to the later case.

Comment: @SridharRatnakumar They are not shy, maybe a bit anxious in social situations but simply incapable of relating to the person's state of mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That kind of person is "socially inept."

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Socially+Inept

Answer (score 3):

socially clumsy where clumsy, in particular:

> awkward in movement or in handling things.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for ***[insensitive](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/insensitive)*** (or ***[unsensitive](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unsensitive)***), or not ***[sensitive](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sensitive)***, as in the sense of "not being responsive to or aware of feelings, moods, reactions". Also, perhaps you can use ***unempathetic***.

Comment: The usual antonym of *sensitive* is *insensitive*.

Comment: @WS2: Hi, do you think it is better now?

Comment: *Unsensitive* is not unheard of, but in the OED *insensitive* has a much larger entry. Bear in mind that I am British, but to me *unsensitive* sounds like something a non-native speaker might say. Would you happen to be German? I have had German colleagues who have particular difficulty with their *uns* and their *ins*  talking about something being *unpossible* or *inoffcial*.

Answer (score 2):

The psychologist Simon Baron-Cohen has a term that I believe fits your definition perfectly,

*Mindblindness*

> impairment in mindreading

Mindreading, according to Simon-

> is the natural way in which we interpret, predict, and participate in
>   social behavior and communication.

[Source](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/026252225X)

So mindreading is an important part of [empathetic accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empathic_accuracy) which relates directly to ones ability to be socially literate, so I'd say your best synonym for someone who is "socially illiterate" would be *mindblind*.

Answer (score 1):

A **"poor personality decoder"**, not exactly an idiom but conveys the idea.

You might also say **"ingenuous"** or **"naïve"**.

> - ingenuous (adj) - (said of a person or action) innocent and unsuspecting. [Google](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=gullible+definition&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&gfe_rd=cr&ei=PckCVu7xHqak8wfSy5foDw&gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=define+ingenuous)
> - naive (adj) - deficient in worldly wisdom or informed judgment; especially :  credulous [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naive)

Answer (score 1):

I would describe the person as *not sociable*, thus [***insociable*** <sub>Merriam-Webster</sub>](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insociable). I would take this to mean the person, for what ever reason, is not capable of normal social interactions.

You would think that [*unsociable* <sub>Merriam-Webster</sub>](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unsociable) would be a synonym, but it is not. I would consider someone described as *unsociable* to mean the person is hostile towards social interactions.

Answer (score 0):

**Apath:** someone who is [apathetic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/apathetic)

> [The Sociopath-Empath-Apath triad](https://psychopathresistance.wordpress.com/2015/04/06/the-sociopath-empath-apath-triad/)
>
> - Sociopath — the one with the personality disorder.
> - Empath — an individual who is highly perceptive, insightful and sensitive to another’s emotions.
> - Apath — someone who is apathetic and likely to do the sociopath’s bidding.

Answer (score 0):

use any of the following adverbs paired with any of the following adjectives

Adverbs:
socially
emotionally

Adjectives
awkward
tone-deaf
inept
impaired
myopic